# Export a list of tuples to a csv in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
fruits = [
   ('apple', [('red', 0.25), ('green', 0.21), ('brown', 0.16)]), 
   ('grapes', [('green', 0.88), ('red', 0.76), ('black', 0.59)])
]
```

Each tuple contains 3 colours of fruits and 3 scores and I want the name of the fruit to be repeated thrice along with colour and score.

I want to export this list of tuples to a csv in the following format:

```
fruit     colour          score
apple      red             0.25
apple      green           0.21
apple      brown           0.16

grapes     green           0.88
grapes     red             0.76
grapes     black           0.59
```

Can anyone help me to do it in Python

Comment: Have you tried anything which is not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably libraries that can help you with that, but a pure python way would be

```py
fruits = [('apple', [('red', 0.25), ('green', 0.21), ('brown', 0.16)]), ('grapes', [('green', 0.88), ('red', 0.76), ('black', 0.59)])]

lines = ["fruit, color, score"] # list of lines in the output file (hardcode headers)

# loop through every type of fruit
# enumerate will give the key (i) and value (ftype) for every fruit type. for i in range(len(fruits)) would've worked too
for i, ftype in enumerate(fruits):

    # for each fruit type, loop through the colors
    for color in fruits[i][1]:
        # add a line to the CSV for every color
        # if you don't know how format works, look it up. It's really useful
        # the star unpacks the tuple
        lines.append("{}, {}, {}".format(ftype[0], *color))

print("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the code if possible

Comment: is that enough?